# WordPress installation on Windows Server 2003 (IIS)

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, wordpress

I am having horrible time setting up WordPress on a Windows Server 2003 machine.

I've set up MySQL and created a database called `wordress`. Uname called WordPress with pwd WordPress as well. So in wp-config.php file I changed 3 things, db name, uname, pwd all to WordPress. host stays localhost.  I opened IIS and  new website (pointed directory to my new WordPress directory).  Gave it port 8080 because there is already a site running on port 80.

When I go to http://localhost:8080/wp-admin/install.php I get an error saying

```
This either means that the username and password information in your wp-config.php file is incorrect or we can't contact the database server at localhost. This could mean your host's database server is down.

•Are you sure you have the correct username and password?
•Are you sure that you have typed the correct hostname?
•Are you sure that the database server is running?
```

I AM able to connect to mysql using same credentials via command prompt.

What could be the error here? I am completley lost.

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need to change the port just because something else is running there, as long as it's in its own directory, you're fine (that just needs to be the root of that site. Of course, if you want it to be at the root, then it needs it's own port :)

Have you been able to connect to MySQL using any other tools inside IIS? Specifically, any others written in PHP?

Do you have the "latest and greatest" [PHP](http://windows.php.net/download/) and [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.1.html#win32) installed?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, no to ask the obvious, but did you give your user wordpress access to the wordpress DB from the localhost on the mysql server?